# KineticJS transitionTo scale

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I am working on a canvas project in Kinetic JS. I would like to know if there is a way of changing the scale of an object in the transitionTo method. Below is a simplified version of my code. I realise that you can do this by using the animate method but for reasons that would take a lot to explain i don't want to do it this way.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1600,
        height: 1200
    });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var book = new Image();
    book.onload = function () {
        bookImg = new Kinetic.Image ({ x: 800, y: 680, image:book, name:book, offset: [85.5, 106], opacity: 0,});

        layer.add(bookImg);
        stage.add(layer);
    }
book.src = "images/book.png";

    setTimeout(function() {
       bookImg.transitionTo({ x: 800, y: 680, opacity: 1, duration: 4, });
    }, 1000);



};
```

So within that transition to i want to alter the scale of the object. So have the original scale as something like 0.5 going up to 1. However I can't find any documentation to help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Using

scale:[0.5,0.5]

and then 

scale:[1,1]

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `scale` property to change it from:

> ```
> bookImg = new Kinetic.Image({
>    x: 100,
>    y: 110,
>    image: book,
>    name: book,
>    offset: [85.5, 106],
>    opacity: 0,
>    scale: { x:0.5, y:0.5 }
> ```
>
> });

to:

> ```
> bookImg.transitionTo({
>    x: 100,
>    y: 110,
>    opacity: 1,
>    duration: 4,
>    scale: { x:1, y:1 }
> ```
>
> });

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/8t8H5/1/)

Comment: Ah i see i was missing out the x: and y: will give it a go

Comment: +1, although to avoid confusion, the x and y are not required here.  Here's an update on the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vMkfK